# Xamarin.Forms + ReactiveUI navigation, IRoutableViewModel remove/hide title bar that contains content of UrlPathSegment

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I am using Xamarin.Forms + ReactiveUI navigation. I have a viewmodel that implements IRoutableViewModel and have a property UrlPathSegment = "Main". How do i hide or remove the "top bar" that has the name of the view/viewmodel stated in the UrlPathSegment?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Excellent you have found the answer for yourself.

Although I would like to share this solution since you're working with ReactiveUI, you can create an extension method, like this:

```cs
    public static class PageExtensions
    {
        public static Page WithoutNavBar(this Page view)
        {
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(view, false);
            return view;
        }
    }
```

And you can use it like this (on your AppBootstrapper):

```cs
     Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => new Login().WithoutNavBar(), typeof(IViewFor<LoginViewModel>));
```

In this way your page won't have Navigation Bar.

Answer (score 1):

just found the answer myself here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-remove-navigation-bar-for-navigation-page-in-xamarin-forms/

NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your issue by yourself, please remember to mark your reply as answer, it is beneficial to other community members who face the same issue, thanks.